# Make a if loop according to what returns the ajax html(data) 

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to make a if loop according to what returns html(data), so how can I get in my ajax script a var returned by "form_treatment.php" ? I want to close the colorbox (a lightbox) containing myForm only if "form_treatment.php" returns a var PHP with a "true" value.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
  var myForm = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'form_treatment.php',
    data: myForm.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
       $('#message').html(data);
       // Make a if loop according to what returns html(data)
    }
  }); 
  return false;
});
```

form.php :

```
<form method="post" action="form_treatment.php" >
    <input type="text" name="user_name" value="Your name..." /> 
    <button type="submit" >OK</button>
</form>
```

form_treatment.php :

```
if ( empty($_POST['user_name']) ){      
        $a = false;
        $b = "Name already used.";      
} else { 
    $already_existing = verify_existence( $_POST['user_name'] ); 
    // verification in the DB, return true or false

    if( $already_existing ){
        $a = false;
        $b = "Name already used.";
    } else {    
        $a = true;
        $b = "Verification is OK";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `dataType : 'json'` inside your `$.ajax()` call, and then, in your php file, respond with nothing but a json object such as:

```
{ "success" : true, "msg" : 'Verification is OK' }
```

Then, inside your `$.json()` success function, you can access anything from the server's response like so:

```
if (data.success) {
    alert(data.msg);
}
```

I know you said you want to loop, but that's just an example. Note that PHP has a great little function called json_encode() that can turn an array into a json object that your JavaScript will pick up just fine.

Comment: Hi it's very interesting because if form_treatment.php don't return an echo but a var like $a="Verification is OK"; , I wonder how make a loop whith $a ? Can you tell me precisely how use json in my ajax script ? and maybe where use json_encode() in form_treatment.php ?

Comment: @Anon Instead of saying `$a = true` and `$b = "Verification is ok"` use an array, like this: `$output = array('success' => true, 'msg' => "Verification is ok");` and then `echo json_encode($output);`

Comment: @Anon Or if you want to use `$a` and `$b`, then use `array('a' => true, 'b' => "Verification is ok")` instead. (But if you do that, then javascript needs to reference `data.a` and `data.b`)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
  var myForm = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'form_treatment.php',
    data: myForm.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {

       // if data is a variable like '$a="Verification is OK"':
       eval(data);

       if ($a == 'Verification is OK')
         $("#colorBox").close() // or whatever the close method is for your plugin
       else 
         $('#message').html($a);
    }
  }); 
  return false;
});
```

Comment: If form_treatment.php don't return an echo but a var like $a="Verification is OK"; , how make a loop whith $a ? data doesn't work then ?

Comment: oddly enough it doesn't work, I change my first post and try it : success: function(data){
       eval(data);
       
          if ($a == true){
        $("#errors").html($b);
       } else {
        $("#errors").html($b); 
       }      
      
      }

Answer (score 0):

The var "data" is the response being passed back from your PHP file. Therefore, you can do something like:

```
    ...success: function (data) {
        if (data == 'Verification is OK') {
           // Make a if loop according to what returns html(data)
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, I changed the form_treatment.php content, how make my loop in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a simple comparison in your `success` function in the ajax request, like this:

```
success: function (data) {
   $('#message').html(data);
   if(data == 'Verification is OK')
   {
       // make the lightbox show
   }
}
```

Comment: hi, I changed the form_treatment.php content in my first post, how make my loop in this case ?